# How to keep the spaces in a string while doing for loop in tcl

Tags: for-loop, tcl, toupper

HI I have a string like **{  Its A Very Good Day! Isn't It  }**. I have to change all the first letter of every word to lower case but the spaces should also be there. For changing to upper case I have used the following code but I do not know how to include the spaces as well. 
The code is:

```
set wordlist {  Its A Very Good Day! Isn't It  }    
set newlistupper [list]    
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $wordlist]} {incr i} {
set word [lindex $wordlist $i]
set newupper [string toupper $word 0 0]
lappend newlistupper $newupper
}
puts $newlistupper
```

I want to know how to keep the spaces also in the output. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify your current script a little bit like so:

```
set wordlist {  Its A Very Good Day! Isn't It  }    
set newlistlower [list]    
foreach word [regexp -inline -all -- {\W+|\w+} $wordlist] {
    set newlower [string tolower $word 0 0]
    lappend newlistlower $newlower
}
puts [join $newlistlower ""]
```

`[regexp -inline -all -- {\W+|\w+} $wordlist]` splits the string into word and non-word characters, which means you get to keep spaces and punctuations and so on.

`foreach` allows you to get each word (spaces get into the loop as well, but `string tolower` won't be affecting them).

This will also work on strings such as:

```
set wordlist {Its A Very Good Day! Isn't It--RIGHT  }
```

to give:

```
{its a very good day! isn't it--rIGHT  }
```

(Braces put to show that the trailing space on the right is kept)

Comment: When I run this code it is working for me but for the word isnt't to make it uppercase it is taking isn't as two words giving Isnt'T. How do i make the computer consider it as one word? @Jerry

Comment: @user2533429 You can edit the regexp to be: `[regexp -inline -all -- {\W+|\w+(?:'\w)?} $wordlist]` to do that. Do you have more cases like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a similar technique to my answer for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17928956/7552):

```
set sentence {  Its A Very Good Day! Isn't It  }
set lc [subst -nob -nov [regsub -all {\s[[:upper:]]} $sentence {[string tolower "&"]}]]
puts ">$lc<"
```

```
>  its a very good day! isn't it  <
```

Another way to do it

```
% regexp -all -inline -indices {\s[[:upper:]]} $sentence 
{1 2} {5 6} {7 8} {12 13} {17 18} {22 23} {28 29}
% set lc $sentence
  Its A Very Good Day! Isn't It  
% foreach match [regexp -all -inline -indices {\s[[:upper:]]} $sentence ] {
    set lc [string replace $lc {*}$match [string tolower [string range $lc {*}$match]]]
}
% puts ">$lc<"
>  its a very good day! isn't it  <
```